# Legitimizing a web request so that the server allows the request through

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to run the following code, but it keeps producing the HTTP error 502. I think the reason for the error is because the website knows that a program is trying to scrape information from it. Thus, it disallows the request. Is there a way to trick the server to think that this is a legitimate web request? I have tried adding headers, but it still does not work.

```
import urllib.request


# Function: Convert information within html document to a text file
# Append information to the file
def html_to_text(source_html, target_file):

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    print(source_html)
    r = opener.open(source_html)
    response = r.read()
    print(response)
    temp_file = open(target_file, 'w+')
    temp_file.write(response.__str__())


source_address = "https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/all?s=*&t=A&m=SG&r=&b=0"
target_location = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\TheLastPuff\\Source\\yahoo_ticker_symbols.txt"

html_to_text(source_address, target_location)
```

Comment: It works for me. How much requests did you send to them? They might detect your experimenting as a bruteforce or dos attack, and blacklisted some fingerprint of your requests

Comment: Is there a way to trick the server to think that the request is from a legitimate browser?

Comment: Yes. Capture the traffic sent by your browser, and copy the header values into your python script.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some amendments to the code and have achieved what I required.

```
import urllib.request
import gzip


# Function: Convert information within html document to a text file
# Append information to the file
def html_to_text(source_html, target_file):

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    # These headers are necessary to ensure that the website thinks that a browser is retrieving information
    # not a program.
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0'),
                         ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
                         ('Accept-encoding', 'gzip, deflate'),
                         ('Accept-language', 'en-US,en;q=0.5'),
                         ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                         ('Host', 'sg,finance.yahoo.com'), ]
    r = opener.open(source_html)

    # Check from the "Response Headers" in Firebug whether the content is encoded
    # Since the content is encoded in gzip format, decompression is necessary
    response = gzip.decompress(r.read())

    # The response headers would mention the "charset" from there the encoding type can be obtained
    response = response.decode(encoding='utf-8')
    print(response)
    temp_file = open(target_file, 'w+')
    temp_file.write(response)


source_address = "https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/all?s=*&t=A&m=SG&r=&b=0"
target_location = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\TheLastPuff\\Source\\yahoo_ticker_symbols.txt"

html_to_text(source_address, target_location)
```